# Catching all Server with SQL Server (any Version) installed using SSCM

Tags: sql-server, sccm

I am trying to create a server collection which collects all Server with SQL Server installed on them in a smart way. I created a Collection and added already some servers using the criterion properties and as shown in the screenshot.
Now I don't want to add 100 SQL Versions listed on the right part of the screenshot manually to my criteria.
So I thought I will just rework the Query Statement myself. But I didn't find a way to copy all the SQL versions listed... (Also I don't have access to the DB behind SSCM)

And if I use a query using `is like Microsoft SQL Server` I will get plenty of native clients, which I don't need.

Can someone help out a rookie here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following query, it will only show machines with Windows Server OS with SQL Server installed :

select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System  where SMS_R_System.ResourceId in (select distinct SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID  from SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName Like 'Microsoft SQL Server %')
AND SMS_R_System.OperatingSystemNameandVersion like "%server%"

I've found a couple of good sites that have a lot of query samples. I use the one by Anders Rodland quite a lot, have found it very helpful. Hope this all helps

http://www.andersrodland.com/ultimate-sccm-querie-collection-list/

Comment: I  found some queries as well, but my result set is changing with every one of them, even though it seems that they all do the same.